# C-style string find and replace function

Tags: c++, string, replace

I've been trying to write a function as part of a custom string class (learning to create my own string class without relying on std::string), but I can't figure out what's wrong.

```
void String::FindAndReplace(const char* subString, const char* replaceString)
{
    int offset = strlen(replaceString) - strlen(subString);

    int subStringIndex = FindSubstring(subString);

    char* newString = new char[strlen(m_string) + offset + 1];
    strcpy(newString, m_string);

    for (int i = subStringIndex + offset; i < strlen(newString); i++)
    {
        newString[i] = m_string[i - offset];
    }

    for (int i = subStringIndex; i < strlen(replaceString) + subStringIndex; i++)
    {
        newString[i] = replaceString[i - subStringIndex];
    }

    m_string = newString;
}
```

Every time I run this not only does it not result in the expected string, but I get a heap corruption message.

The string is "Help, I'm a caterpillar!!" and I want to replace "caterpillar" with "bird", the string instead becomes "Help,caterpibird!!" and then exits with the error message I mentioned previously.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `strcpy(newString, m_string)` copies the old string into the new buffer, but the new buffer isn't big enough (since when `replaceString` is shorter than `subString`, `offset` is a negative number). You're trashing memory beyond the allocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int subStringIndex = FindSubstring(subString);

char* newString = new char[strlen(m_string) + offset + 1];
strcpy(newString, m_string);
```

There are at least two bugs here.

Your FindAndReplace() method can receive a `subString` that doesn't actually exist. Your code does not appear to handle this situation.

Then second bug is when`replaceString` is shorter than `subString`, which is the case in your example. A new, smaller `newString` gets allocated (because `offset` is negative), shorter than the existing `m_string`.

Immediately afterwords, you are `strcpy()`ing the current, longer string, into the new, shorter buffer.

Buffer overflow. Heap corruption. Undefined behavior.